# How to find the parent call of a call in Twilio using C#

Tags: c#, twilio, ivr

Sorry for the terribly worded question. Im using Twilio and im trying to create some reporting for users. I have a few different numbers that are called and then depending on what the caller does during the call, they may be transferred to our call center.

I need to know the number of calls that are transferred for each number.

When they call, a CallSid is created. Once the caller is transferred, a second CallSid is created with a new property called ParentCallSid. The ParentCallSid of the second call matches the CallSid of the first call.

I need to take that ParentCallSid and find the original CallSid so i can see which number they called. I will be doing this for each call in the list. So it will need to be some kind of loop. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this one is too difficult, it's just a matter of pulling the pieces together. If you look at this example:  http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-get-example-1 (select C#), you should get back a "call" object.

One of the properties on that object will be ParentCallSid so you can change the above example from this:

```
Console.WriteLine(call.StartTime);
```

to this:

```
Console.WriteLine(call.ParentCallSid);
```

Then you can get information on that Call including the ParentCallSid and repeat until you get to the first call.